# Why would this event handler code cause a Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Error (only present on live server, ok on dev)?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, object-reference

Here is the code for the button click event;

```
  Protected Sub CompetenciesButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CompetenciesButton.Click
        Dim con As String = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("foo").ToString()
        Dim selectedrow As String = Competencies.SelectedValue.ToString
        Dim s As String = "SELECT * from foo WHERE (" & selectedrow & " =1)"
        Dim DataAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(s, con)
        Dim Result As New DataTable
        If Not IsNothing(DataAdapter) Then
            DataAdapter.Fill(Result)
            DataAdapter.Dispose()
        End If
        GV.DataSource = Result
        GV.DataBind()
        GV2.DataSource = Result
        GV2.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Here is the stack:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   administration_Search.CompetenciesButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) +28
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +105
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +107
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +7
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +11
   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +33
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1746
```

Everything works fine offline in VS2008 but I get this error after publishing.

Thanks.

Comment: which line is line 28 exactly?

Comment: that is the DataAdapter.Dispose() line, thanks, phil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your WebConfiguration the same on both dev and live?

If you are missing the *foo* connection string on the live server, then the `con` object would be set to null.

And if you are still having trouble catching it, then try including a try/catch block, setting a string variable `progress` outside of try, updating it every line within the logic, and logging the error along with the current value of `progress`. This should help to narrow down where it is happening.